# TimePicker lost the Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapp TimePicker control, I define it in the following way:

```
<Controls:TimePicker Culture="it-IT" Width="200" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Start pause" SelectedTime="{Binding Stop, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and this is the property for bind the value:

```
private TimeSpan? _stop;
public TimeSpan? Stop
{
        get { return _stop; }
        set
        {
            _stop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
}
```

this is my `OnPropertyChanged();` implementation:

```
public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected new virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This is the situation: when I change the value on the control this doesn't execute the binding, this only happen in the fist time, the second time that I execute the binding the value is taken correctly. If I put a breakpoint both on get and set instead, seems that the binding is done correctly. I don't what'happean.

Comment: remove the `IsAsync`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Wow! Working, but why with isAsync not? Could you enlight me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `IsAsync = true`. IsAsync should only be used, when your getter is expected to return the result with noticeable delay. Or as Microsoft puts it:

> Use the IsAsync property when the get accessor of your binding source property might take a long time. One example is an image property with a get accessor that downloads from the Web. Setting IsAsync to true avoids blocking the UI while the download occurs.

So basically the getter is executed in another thread and returns the value to the binding once it's done. No idea how WPF actually handles setters with `IsAsync`, maybe someone else can add that part.

Comment: @Heisenberg If you really want `async` behavior, then create a `Task` in the code-behind and after completion write the value to the bound property.